# Salesforce Reports and Dashboard dynamic dates

Tags: reporting, case, dashboard, report-chart

Hi when I create a report for case object.

I create no. of case handled by 3 user say A,B,C and I want this report to display weekly status.

I created a Report With Date Field Opened Date and Range to This week .

Next tab From  and To automatically fills from and To date for this week.

My  question is once I create the report and Chart for this. Will it automatically update the dashboard for next with the Date from 09/18/2016-09/24/2016.

Hope this helps 
[image]
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the dynamic data selectors as described in below documentation link, the report and dashboard dates will move along with the actual dates.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_dates.htm

Judging from your description you are fine. In order to be 100% sure, you'd need to include a screenshot (or wait until next week ;-) )

Comment: I have added the screen shots.

Comment: Yes if you keep range as 'this week' it will automatically update the report and any dashboard based on it. The 2 date fields are there just to help you determine whether you picked the right range filter.

Comment: so similarly if we Select Today as a range it will refresh every day considering as today right.

Comment: Correct Today will select the current date, something to be careful of though is if you have users in different timezones as their Today will be different from each other.